# ElasticSearch mass delete by URL

Tags: elasticsearch

I have about 8 million documents(with URL) in the ElasticSearch(v.0.90) index but only 3,5 millions documents are "valid"(need to be searched within). I have a list of all "valid" URLs(no special template here).

How can I delete other 4,5M documents from the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DeleteByQuery API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/delete-by-query/).
Then, you will probably need to run [Optimize](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-optimize/).

But you will need for that a lot of free disk space.

Comment: the main difference is that the term query is not analyzed. Are you going to identify the documents to be deleted via a big list of urls? How is that field analyzed?

Comment: used termQuery. url field - not analyzed. (if url filed was analized termQuery found nothing because it parses/tokenized urls)